# Check if connected to a VPN in shell script

Tags: bash, shell-script, shell, curl, openvpn

I am trying to create a shell script that checks if a user is connected to a VPN. I am a beginner in shell scripts though, but here is my logic.

```
#!/bin/bash
set -euo pipefail
IFS=$'\n\t'

PUBLIC_IP="123.456.789.123%"  
CURRENT_IP="$(curl api.ipify.org)"
```

I want to compare the current IP with my regular IP, and if they match, it should `echo "disconnected"` otherwise, `echo "connected"`.

How would I go about doing that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your script you can write something like

```
if [ "${CURRENT_IP}" = "${PUBLIC_IP}" ]; then
  echo "disconnected"
else
  echo "connected"
fi
```

Please notice that you have a percent sign (`%`) in PUBLIC_IP that would make the comparison always fail.